# Open PDF in VBA shell command access denied error

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

I'm opening PDF files with this command

```
AdobeApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
AdobeFile = "\\path\filename.pdf"
StartAdobe = Shell("" & AdobeApp & " " & AdobeFile & "", 1)
```

Generally it works well except with some PDF files that I get an error message saying 'There was an error opening this document. Access denied.'

I can open the PDF file with no issues if I copy the link in windows explorer or if I double click on the file in the same computer.

Is there any settings I can use in the shell command to prevent this error?

Comment: Does it give that error to the same files consistently? Or is it a "random" error?

Comment: And is it always the same files? And are those files actually closed before attempting to open or potentially in use?

Comment: It's suprising that works at all given you have no quotes around either of the paths? `StartAdobe = Shell("""" & AdobeApp & """ """ & AdobeFile & """", 1)`

Comment: BruceWayne, yes, it gives the error to the same file consistently

Comment: QHarr, yes, always the same files and yes, the files are closed before attempting to open

Comment: Tim, I don't know how it was working, but it has been working. I've tried what what you suggested with the additional " and actually it worked. Thanks for resolving my issue

Comment: Tim, it has not resolved the error for all files though. There are still some files where I get the error

Answer (score 0):

Adding the second set of quotes around the paths [as Tim suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617938/open-pdf-in-vba-shell-command-access-denied-error/75546932#comment94097725_53617938) fixed it for me:

> ```
> StartAdobe = Shell("""" & AdobeApp & """ """ & AdobeFile & """", 1)
> ```